# DateTimeFormatter could not be parsed using "HH:mm E d MMM YYYY" pattern

Tags: java, parsing, time, java-time

I am retrieving a date/time from an external data source, this is returned in the following format "14:30 Sat 05 May" with no year.

I've been trying to parse this to a LocalDateTime unsuccessfully. The data returned does not return a year as it is an assumption that we are always operating in the current year.

```
//date to parse
String time = "14:30 Sat 05 May";

//specify date format matching above string
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm E d MMM YYYY") ;

//we do not have a year returned but i can make the assumption we use the current year
LocalDateTime formatDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time, formatter).withYear(2018);
```

The above code throws the following exception

Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '14:30 Sat 05 May' could not be parsed at index 16

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it simply the case, that your string ends and the parser still expects the " YYYY" part as declared in the pattern?

Comment: @JanOssowski yes thank you, i incorrectly assumed .withYear(2016) called on the LocalDateTime negated the need for me to do this. Thank you issue solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LocalDateTime.parse()` expects a `String` that represents a valid date, which the `year` part.
You cannot set the year after invoking this method in this way :

```
LocalDateTime.parse(time, formatter).withYear(2018);
```

The year has to be set before because otherwise `parse()` throws `DateTimeParseException`.

As a workaround you may concatenate the current year in the input.

Some additional notes:

- the pattern you use and the input date in textual format don't match exactly.
- You don't specify a `Locale` for the parsing operation.
  It means that it will work according to the local where the JVM is run.
  To ensure that it works in any case, you should specify the `Locale`.

So you could try something like :

```
//date to parse
String time = "14:30 Sat 05 May";
time +=  " " + LocalDate.now().getYear();

//specify date format matching above string
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm EEE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US) ;

//we do not have a year returned but i can make the assumption we use the current year
LocalDateTime formatDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time, formatter);
```

Comment: A solution is to specify a default year as part of the formatter. See the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257671/642706).

Answer (score 4):

## Default year

Specify a default year in your [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), using the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class by calling [`parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,long)) and specifying the year-field with [`ChronoField.YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("HH:mm E d MMM")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, 2018)  // <------
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

With this formatter instead of yours:

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "14:30 Sat 05 May" , formatter )
```

…I get:

> 2018-05-05T14:30

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/lLBtNO).

Points to note:

- Your format pattern string needs to match the parsed string end-to-end. So when your date-time string doesn’t have a year in it, don’t include `YYYY` in your format pattern.
- In any case don’t use uppercase `YYYY` here. It’s for week-based year and only useful with week numbers. If your string had had a year in it, you should have used `uuuu` or lowercase `yyyy`.
- Make it a habit to give explicit locale to your formatter so you know it also works on other computers, and on yours when one day you play with its settings.

Comment: FYI, that year number could be soft-coded by calling [`Year.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#now(java.time.ZoneId)).